# Is there a local theme layout XML file other than local.xml?

Tags: layout, magento-1, theme, parent-child-theme, theme-fallback

I've built a theme by creating and editing the following file:

```
frontend/mypackage/default/layout/local.xml
```

I have a store view "site1", and wish to make exceptions on the default local.xml of "mypackage", so I created this file:

```
frontend/mypackage/site1/layout/local.xml
```

However, as soon as I create this file, Magento skips the default local.xml changes.

How do I tell Magento to use the local.xml from default, and add the changes in site1's local.xml to that?

Comment: No way. Sorry. Good question by the way.

Comment: I'm facing this exact same scenario.  I was to extend the local.xml from the default theme, not completely replace it.  It's too bad it replaces it entirely with the selected sub-theme.

Comment: Is there nothing like a default.xml? Or could we hack the Magento core code which traverses the xml-files, to also check for a default.xml?

Answer (score 7):

Since Magento 1.9 you can add custom layout updates in `etc/theme.xml` like this:

```
<theme>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <my_theme>
                <file>my_theme.xml</file>
            </my_theme>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

If you define your theme specific layouts like this instead of using `local.xml`, it is easy to add another update in the child theme.

Unfortunately, the same problem goes with theme.xml that only the one from your actual theme is used, not the one from parent themes. But there is much less duplication.

Example `theme.xml` for the child theme:

```
<theme>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <my_theme>
                <file>my_theme.xml</file>
            </my_theme>
            <my_child_theme>
                <file>my_child_theme.xml</file>
            </my_child_theme>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

Source and more info: http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml

Answer (score 5):

Magento does not merge local.xml changes from other local.xml files. The way Magento theme fallback works is that any file found in the current theme/package will be preferred and used over any other theme/package file similarly named.

In this way you cannot create a merged override. This will be possible in Magento 2, but is not possible in Magento 1.x.

Unfortunately you will have to copy it to your local theme from the default and make your modifications there.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Phil is absolutely right but theoretically there is a workaround (not that pretty though).

You can create a custom module which will introduce the layout update. Then in the module you can check if the store view is not the one that is required and remove this layout update.

The bad thing about this approach is that you will hardcode the store view. And overall this doesn't look pretty.