# Multiple Layout Files - How Are They Called?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

I am a developer familiar with HTML, CSS and JavaScript but not Magento conventions. In particular, I'm having trouble with the layout files.

Some themes have one, some have over a dozen, and some are nested. How are these layout files called? I read somewhere else that they are all defined in a `config.xml` but I can't find that for each theme.

For example, in one theme I have in `app/design/frontend/THEMENAME/default/layout`

```
-local.xml
-sales
--billingagreement.xml
--recurring_profile.xml
```

In other themes I don't even have a `local.xml`. So my question is, I thought the layout files controlled the placement of blocks, widgets, the content in general. But how does the layouts work when there are multiple of them and they are specific to different programmatic circumstances?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism where is this "configuration" mentioned in that answer? It says each module has a configuration but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the layout XML files are specified in `config.xml` files. Usually, each module has one layout XML file for the shop frontend and one for the admin panel

1. Module specific layout XML files are defined in `app/code/[pool]/[vendor]/[module]/etc/config.xml` like this

   ```
           <frontend>
              <layout>
                   <updates>
                       <[module]>
                           <file>[filename].xml</file>
                       </[module]>
                   </updates>
               </layout>
           </frontend>
   ```
2. The modules place their default layout files in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout`, but each theme can override them in `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout`
3. `local.xml` is a special case. It is not defined explitly, but if a theme contains it, it is always loaded **after** all module specific files, so that you can override anything in there. It is considered best practice to not override complete files as described above, but make modifications via `local.xml`
4. Another special case is `etc/theme.xml`. More info: [Is there a local theme layout XML file other than local.xml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17699/is-there-a-local-theme-layout-xml-file-other-than-local-xml/72907#72907)

Comment: I understand everything except this module business. What is a module, aren't they additions to the core? Where is the `config.xml` that defines the layout files for the default theme?

Comment: modules are not only additions to the core (they can be, as part of an extension), but also the core itself consists of modules. the core modules are in `app/code/core` and there you will find the config.xml files

Comment: also, because you asked for "layout files for the default theme": the modules define the layout XML file names **independent of the theme**. Magento then looks for each of them in the theme directory and falls back to those in the default theme if it cannot find them

Comment: so if i want to create a new theme do I need to essentially create a new module to avoid editing the core?

Comment: No, although it is generally a good idea for theme specific features. Why would you want to edit the core? You can use  `local.xml` for theme specific layout instructions

Comment: Well, because I am editing an existing theme that may or may not be part of a custom module, going back to my original question, it has `local.xml` but never references the `billingagreement.xml` so I don't understand their relationship, it must be defined in a custom module then?

Comment: themes are never part of a module. but you are right, billingagreement.xml comes from a custom module and this theme overrides its default layout. it might even be that this is "just in case" and you don't have that module. then the file has no effect. To help you further, it would be good to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: okay well, i'll accept your answer as I think we are getting outside of the scope of the original question. :P

Answer (score 1):

Each layout files declared in any `config.xml`  from an active module are loaded and merged into one big xml file.

Here is an example on how the layout file is declared in [`config.xml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml#L735)

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <catalog>
                <file>catalog.xml</file>
            </catalog>
            <map>
                <file>catalog_msrp.xml</file>
            </map>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

This means that from the catalog module 2 layout files will be loaded. `catalog.xml` and `catalog_msrp.xml`.
The files are searched in the current package and theme (declared in config), if it's not there then the file is searched in the default declared theme. If it's not there it will be searched for in the `default`  named folder of that package and if it's not there either it  will be searched in `base/default` folder.

After all the module files are loaded, at the end the file called `local.xml` of your current theme will be added also.

When the big file is merged and cached, on a page, certain tags will be loaded depending on the page.
For example in the cart page the tag called `checkout_cart_index` will be loaded, all the blocks declared inside it will be instantiated and information will be displayed on the page.
This is a nice way of extending a page without changing the core code.

Comment: Sorry, but where is this config file? In the core? How do I edit it safely or see the one that is being applied currently?

Comment: Every module should have a `etc/config.xml` file. You should not edit the core. You should create your own module and add your own `config.xml` file where you declare the layout file. Then create the layout file.  Read this for more info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

Comment: So in the Magento hierarchy a module encompasses a theme? Is this correct? Is a theme appears to not have a `config.xml` or a module, does that mean it is inheriting?